# Unable to access static JSON file from dropbox in my Android app project

Tags: android, json, dropbox

I am making a music player android app and i cant figure out why my JSON file isn't being run. I have stored my file in dropbox and i am using it externally.

```
public class RemoteJSONSource implements MusicProviderSource {

private static final String TAG = LogHelper.makeLogTag(RemoteJSONSource.class);

protected static final String CATALOG_URL =
    "http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/music.json";

private static final String JSON_MUSIC = "music";
private static final String JSON_TITLE = "title";
private static final String JSON_ALBUM = "album";
private static final String JSON_ARTIST = "artist";
private static final String JSON_GENRE = "genre";
private static final String JSON_SOURCE = "source";
private static final String JSON_IMAGE = "image";
private static final String JSON_TRACK_NUMBER = "trackNumber";
private static final String JSON_TOTAL_TRACK_COUNT = "totalTrackCount";
private static final String JSON_DURATION = "duration";
```

Comment: Could you please also post the part of the code where you actually try to load the json file?

Comment: http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/music.json works in a browser here. Nice jazz json. And it does not look as beeing from DropBox.

Comment: @greenapps this is the code that is running im trying to change the link and using the link from my dropbox and my application crashes because of it. 
The link that im using instead of 'storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/music.json '   is  ' https://www.dropbox.com/s/czqyl12ixaswb52/musiclibrary.json?dl=0 '

Comment: Well put the used url in your code. And show the code where you use the url. You were asked that before. Put all in your post. Not in comments.